# Trusted Web Activity on Android not hiding URL bar

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

I followed the instructions to get a PWA (TWA) on Android as outlined here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa

When I run it on the simulator (without the debugging to skip verification) it works great. The URL bar is hidden.

To test on the simulator, I am installing the same signed APK that I uploaded to Google Play Console:

```
adb install ~/my-app/app/release/app-release.apk
```

I ran logcat to verify it wasn't skipping verification on the simulator (it says so in the log if it's skipping, it's not).

```
adb logcat | grep -e OriginVerifier -e digital_asset_link
```

When I install it on my physical device from Google Play internal test the URL bar isn't hidden. I can see it's hitting `/.well-known/assetlinks.json` in the `access.log` on my server, but the URL bar isn't hidden. I also tested the well-known file could be hit with this tool: https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator.

Any ideas why it wouldn't work on my actual device when it works on the simulator?

Update:

I uploaded the apk directly to my physical device and works great. I think the automatic Google Play signing is messing things up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out! I guess I opted into having Google Play sign my releases with a key they generated. So I simply copied the **App signing certificate** SHA-256 fingerprint under **Release Management -> App Signing** and put it in the assetlinks.json file.